# Should I clone unrecognized partition in disk?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, clonezilla, macrium

I am planning to replace my HDD with an SSD. I am using Macrium Reflect to copy all the data from the HDD to the SSD. But I see a partition that is 7.63GB in size and I don’t know if I need to copy it too. I found out that my HDD (ST1000LX015) is an SSHD that has an 8GB NVMe cache inside it. I wonder if that partition is the cache and if I should copy it to the SSD.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache is completely transparent and invisible for Windows, so this
partition is certainly not that.

I also note that this partition is marked as "Unformatted", so it seems
to have been abandoned after its creation. I would say that there is
no point in copying it.

However, if this disk is the boot disk, it should be copied in totality.

My advice is to copy the entire disk completely, then make your
experiments on the new disk. You could then delete the partition and merge
it with the previous one. In case of an error, you could always copy
again the original disk.